# Need to check the condition for variables and print alert

Tags: arrays, variables

I want to check the condition whether variable countItems is equal to variable countMatchInput if it is equal then it should give an alert Hi. Variable countItems is an array

Javascript code below

```
    var countItems = ["C++", "C#", "VB", "Java and Ruby","Physics", "Chemistry", "Mathematics", "Social Science", "History", "Geography", "Rickshaw", "Bike", "Car", "Bus and Train"];

    function addCounts() {   
    var countMatchInput = document.getElementById("countMatchInput").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = countMatchInput;
    for (var i = 0; i < countItems; i++) {
      if(countItems === countMatchInput)
      {
          alert("Hi");
      }
  }
};
```

Html code is below

```
 <textarea id="countMatchInput"></textarea>
          <button onclick="addCounts()">
            Add
          </button>
        <p id="demo">
        </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop is faulty:

```
var countItems = ["C++", "C#", "VB", "Java and Ruby","Physics", "Chemistry", "Mathematics", "Social Science", "History", "Geography", "Rickshaw", "Bike", "Car", "Bus and Train"];

function addCounts() {   
    var countMatchInput = document.getElementById("countMatchInput").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = countMatchInput;
    for (var i = 0; i < countItems.length; i++) {
        if(countItems[i] === countMatchInput){
            alert("Hi");
        }
  }
};
```